# Formatting PHP to connect with external API

Tags: php, api

I'm trying to send a sales order from woocommerce to an external API. I've managed to POST the json request and can see that it is arriving but I can't get the structure correct so the API accepts the request.

The json request needs to be structured as shown below

```
{
  "customer": "",
  "delivery_instructions": "",
  "delivery_address": {
    "address1": "",
    "address2": ""
  },
  "payment": {
    "method": "",
    "transaction_id": "",
    "amount": ""
  },
  "info": [
    {
      "type": "",
      "code": "",
      "quantity": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

What I am having trouble formatting correctly is the PHP that sends the request to the API in that I am missing the square brackets around the info array

This is my current PHP:

```
// The data to send to the API

$postData = [
    'customer' => '',
    'delivery_instructions' => '',
    'delivery_address' => [ 
      'address1' => '',
      'address2' => ''
    ],
    'payment' => [
      'method' => 'PP',
      'transaction_id' => '',
      'amount' => ''
    ],
    'info' => [ 
      'type' => '',
      'item_code' => '',
      'quantity' => ''
    ],
];
```

But when I POST this the result is

```
{
  "customer": "",
  "delivery_instructions": "",
  "delivery_address": {
    "address1": "",
    "address2": ""
  },
  "payment": {
    "method": "",
    "transaction_id": "",
    "amount": ""
  },
  "info": {
      "type": "",
      "code": "",
      "quantity": ""
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `'lines'` or  `'info'` (don't know which is correct) should be array of arrays.

Comment: Sorry I did have a typo - it is info and I have edited it. I understand it needs to be an array of an array but i just cant get the syntax correct in the php bit.

Comment: @Unkie-Tee .... Check The Ans .. its work for You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I Hope Its Help You :)

```
<?php

 $postData =  [
        'customer' => '',
        'delivery_instructions' => '',
        'delivery_address' => [ 
          'address1' => '',
          'address2' => ''
        ],
        'payment' => [
          'method' => 'PP',
          'transaction_id' => '',
          'amount' => ''
        ],
        'info' => [ 
          'type' => '',
          'item_code' => '',
          'quantity' => ''
        ],
    ];


$val = array();
$val["type"] = '';
$val["item_code"] = '';
$val["quantity"] = '';

$data = array();
$data['info'][] = $val;
//echo json_encode($data);    
$myvalues = array_merge($postData,$data);

echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode($myvalues);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

### Output

```
{  
   "customer":"",
   "delivery_instructions":"",
   "delivery_address":{  
      "address1":"",
      "address2":""
   },
   "payment":{  
      "method":"PP",
      "transaction_id":"",
      "amount":""
   },
   "info":[  
      {  
         "type":"",
         "item_code":"",
         "quantity":""
      }
   ]
}
```

> **NOTE:**  Here I Just Create One Array For Info array Data and then that's output merge into our actually `postData` array and then echo ..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this structure:

```
$postData = new stdClass;
$postData->customer = '';
$postData->delivery_instructions = '';
$postData->delivery_address = (object)array('address1' => '', 'address2' => '');
$postData->payment = (object)array('method' => '', 'transaction_id' => '', 'amount' => '');
$postData->info = array( (object)array('type' => '', 'code' => '', 'quantity' => '') );

print_r( json_encode($postData) );
```

Answer (score -1):

In Php,json data approximate array data